# Handling ETL Failures in Talend

Tags: bigdata, etl, talend

I have several Servers and I have downloaded all files from all servers.
sometimes, one of servers doesn't work properly and the ETL is unable to download files from the faulty server. So, ETL stops and it must be run manually again.
I would like to add intelligence to it so that it skips the faulty server without crashing. Do you have any idea How can I set my ETL to check the server's status. If I know the server status, I can skip it if faulty. For example, if server 3 has a problem, my ETL will be able to jump from 2 to 4 for download files instead of crashing at server 3.

Can anybody help me that how to catch errors and exceptions and show meaningful messages.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Talend DI backgroud, easily you can loop over servers and show what you want in every iteration:

- Put each server parameters : ip, port, login .. in a delimited file
- tFileList that iterate over paramerters files
- tcontextLoad to load parameters into context every loop
- the rest of job that load file from remote server, here use context variables that have values loaded from files
- make a onSubJobError trigger to handle fault server and be sure that your components does not stop if there is an error, there is a check box for that in most components.
- put some tlogRow in the onSubJobOK and onSubJobError.

Answer (score 0):

Usually all the components has 'Die on error' property. By switching it off the job will continue the process even if the download step failed. In case of tFTPGet its in the bottom of the 'Basic settings' tab. You should scroll down to the bottom to see it.
With tWarn and tDie components you can catch the exceptions and log the issues in the desired form.